# Replace elements in list of lists with defined value - Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
L = [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Info:

```
print(type(L))
print(type(L[0]))
print(type(L[0][0]))
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'int'>
```

I'd like to have this as result:

```
L = [[' ', ' ', '*', ' ', ' '],[' ', '*', '*', '*', ' '], ['*','*','*','*',]]
```

*now elements of lists are chr*

Is there a nice way to do this? Of course I could play with fors and iterators but I am looking for something smoother.

Comment: `print([[' ' if j == 0 else "*" for j in i] for i in L])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension to generate a new list keeping the nested structure, using `if`/`else` statements to populate it with `*` or a space accordingly:

```
L = [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

[['*' if i else ' ' for i in l] for l in L]

[[' ', ' ', '*', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', '*', '*', '*', ' '],
 ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*']]
```

Answer (score 1):

For the more general case of more than two values,

```
>>> L = [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 1, 0], [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]]
```

you could also use a dictionary, mapping source elements to target elements...

```
>>> d = {0: " ", 1: "*", 2: "**", 3: "***"}
>>> [[d[x] for x in l] for l in L]
[[' ', ' ', '*', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', '*', '**', '*', ' '],
 ['*', '**', '***', '**', '*']]
```

... or a function doing the same (same result)

```
>>> f = lambda n: ("*" * n) if n else " "
>>> [[f(x) for x in l] for l in L]
```